# EF AssociationSet in Deleted State Error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Not sure what's going on here.  I have a pretty simple model for an online training site with WebUsers and Lessons.  I'm trying to audit when users view a particular lesson. I'm pretty new to EF, so maybe I'm doing something wrong, but code seems straightforward enough.

**Code is very simple:**

```
var webUser = db.WebUsers.Single(x => x.Id =((ProfileCommon)ControllerContext.HttpContext.Profile).WebUserId);
var lesson = db.Lessons.Single(x => x.Id == lessonId);

UserAudit audit = new UserAudit();
audit.WebUser = webUser;            
audit.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
audit.Lesson = lesson;

db.UserAudits.AddObject(audit);
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Error I'm getting:**

```
A relationship from the 'UserAuditLesson' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'UserAudit' must also in the 'Deleted' state.
```

**Below is Entity Model:**
(I can't post images as a new user...but below is the link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Pz0.png

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: i'm having a similar issue. any solution?

Comment: If any of you folks having a problem while deleting objects using db.Parent.Children.Remove(child) - go for db.DeleteObject(child).

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of retrieving audit from database and immediately replacing reference with a new one? It looks like your lesson already have some another `UserAudit` associated in the database and in such case you must also delete that previous `UserAudit` instance otherwise your database will be in inconsistent state violating your referential integrity.

Comment: There is not point...that was an error in my copy paste...I tried minimizing my code to focus on the exact problem and forgot to take that out.  See the updated code.